# EF 4.0 Linq generates weird query when using string.contains with a variable instead of hard coded string

Tags: linq-to-sql, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

When I'm using the following code block(C#):

```
var query = context.Set.Where(o => o.Email.Contains("Mail@gmail.com"));
var stringQuery = ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)query).ToTraceString();
```

linq generates the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM [SET] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Email] LIKE '%Mail@gmail.com%'
```

When I'm using the following code block:

```
string email = "Mail@gmail.com";
var query = context.Set.Where(o => o.Email.Contains(email));
var stringQuery = ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)query).ToTraceString();
```

linq generates the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Set] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Email] LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE N'~'
```

How can I get linq to generate the query like in the first case without having the string hardcoded, and instead passed as a string parameter?

Comment: why do you want this? it seems perfectly fine to me

Comment: the performance of the first query in the DB is way better than the second one.

Comment: I'm also experiencing the huge performance difference. Its about 1:5 for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results you've seen are as they should be.  The reason being, Linq correctly identifies the string literal as hardcoded and assumes that it is not subject to SQL injection and capture (i.e. it is constant and will not be a different value at the point the deferred query is run).

Similarly, it correctly identifies that the variable can vary, and that it could be user input.  It uses a parameterised query which is the suggested/best practice for such cases.

If however you are sure that you would like to override this best practice (because you know better?) =)  then you can walk the expression tree to find the variable access and replace the node with a ConstantExpression instead.  I believe this will cause linq to hardcode the query as you've observed.

[MSDN - Expression Tree Visitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882521%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Pay attention to the `VisitMemberAccess` method, and take a look at [ConstantExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.constantexpression.aspx) [MemberExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.memberexpression.aspx).

Comment: all i'm trying to achieve is better performance, the time that take to the server to reply on the first query is 70 ms and for the second one is 344 ms. as is there any way to achieve better performance without knowing the string's value before it is passed ?

Comment: Interesting.  Can you reproduce the performance differences consecutively and en-masse?  Would you be able to create a small test project that shows this?  The only difference between the two should be the time it takes to evaluate the expression.  If that is the case, take a look at [compiled queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896297.aspx).  Hope they help!

Comment: basically all you need is a DB that contains a table with at least on column of type varchar or nvarchar and execute 2 queries with an identical format to the queries in the post.just don't forget to include client statistics before you run the queries.